# Vertical-align: middle does not align to parent element?

Tags: html, css

According to w3schools, vertical-align: middle property is supposed to align the element that it is applied to to its parent element.

Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. I've been doing some tests and vertical-align actually aligns with the tallest element in the parent... This basically forces me to create an useless element (div) that simply inherits the height of the parent every time I want to vertically align a single element.

A picture will help you understand what I mean better:
[image]

```css
#search-login {
 border: 1px solid black;
 /*text-align: center;*/
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 75px;
}


#search-bar {
 /*
 vertical-align: middle;
 display: inline-block;
 */
 float: left;
 /*border: 1px solid black;*/
 /*padding: 5px;*/
 height: inherit;
 background-color: blue;
 
}

#search-bar-valign-fix {
 height: inherit;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

#search-bar form {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

#search-bar form input[type="text"] {
 width: 500px;
 padding-left: 3px;
 padding-right: 3px;
}

#search-bar form select {
 width: 150px;
}



#login-bar {
 /*
 vertical-align: middle;
 display: inline-block;
 */
 float: right;
 /*
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 5px;
 */
 height: inherit;
 background-color: green;
}

#login-bar-valign-fix {
 height: inherit;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 
}

#login-bar form {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

#login-bar form input[type="text"], #login-bar form input[type="password"] {
 width: 150px;
 padding-left: 3px;
 padding-right: 3px;
}

#create-account {
 text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="login-bar">
<div id="login-bar-valign-fix"></div>
<form method="post">
    <p id="create-account"><a href="sign_up">Create account</a></p>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="submit" value="login">
</form>
</div>

<div id="search-bar">
<div id="search-bar-valign-fix"></div>
<form method="get">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search books">
    By
    <select name="search-by">
        <option value="title">Title</option>
        <option value="authors-name">Author's name</option>
        <option value="genre">Genre</option>
        <option value="language">Language</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
</div>
```

Login and search bar are surrounded by a div called search-login btw.

Now this is what happens if I remove the valign-fix divs...
[image]

Is there a better way to do this? I'm new to css and I find it very complicated to do a simple layout.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Vertical align is working as intended for you: note that there is an extra line of text in the login form (that goes "Create an account"), and it adds the extra height—and this causes the input boxes to appear misaligned, but in both cases **all contents** are actually being properly vertically centered. What you could do is to position the login bar relatively, and use a negative `top` value that is the height of the line of text "Create an account".

Comment: It does work actually. Basically I wanted to know if there was a better alternative than to create these useless divs for vertical-align to work. As soon as I remove them, vertical-align property doesn't work anymore (last picture).

Comment: I think `table-cell` is a better choice, quick demo - http://jsfiddle.net/w4oma21m/ you can get started from there if you like.

Answer (score 0):

it actually centers the items, but you have a link "create an account.." inside the same container. that's why it looks like it's a little bit below the center..

Either you remove the `create an account` or you add a `margin-top: -16px` (or whatever your line-height / font-size is) to the login container